# Extracting data from a .txt in c

Tags: c, algorithm

I have read the topic [How to extract data from a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152424/how-to-extract-data-from-a-file-in-c) but I'm still in trouble with an extraction of data from a file in C because I have a precise request. Here is an example of a .txt I have to deal with:

```
2
3 
x x y z
x x y z
x x y z
4 5
```

The two first integers are important. As we have 2(=M) and 3(=N) in this order at first, it means that the square following those numbers has a format of Nx(M+2), i.e, N the number of rows and M+2 the number of columns  and the last line will have M numbers.

I assume x, y, and z are double precision numbers to highlight what I want to extract.

My goal is to get a code that will generate:
M=2; N=3; x[N][M]={{x,x},{x,x},{x,x}}; y[N]={y,y,y};
z[N]={z,z,z}; t[M] = {4,5};
for any inputs in the files.

Here is what I tried but it doesn't work because I guess I don't really know how to manage the position where we read the file:

```
long i,j,M,N;
FILE *f;
f=fopen("file.txt","r");
fscanf(f,"%ld %ld",&M,&N);
double x[M][N],y[N],z[N],t[M];
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<M;j++)
        fscanf(f,"%g",&x[i][j]);

    fscanf(f,"%g",&y[i]);
    fscanf(f,"%g",&z[i]);
}

for(j=0;j<M;j++)
    fscanf(f,"%g",&t[j]);
```

Comment: Instead of having the inner loop make `N+2` iterations, read the x's first in a loop and then read `y` and `z` with two more `fscanf`s.

Comment: warning: `else if(j=N)` --> `else if(j==N)`

Comment: Besides, your description of the file structure is confusing. 
Please revise it

Comment: @A.S.H my goal is to get the two first integers on two seperates variables, and all different char on a array, i.e. 4 arrays (3 differents of x , y , z) and one of the last line. The file structure description is as I wrote it down on the topic, don't know how to explain more precisely, sorry :/

Comment: I think you need to: 1. correct that `else` in my previous comment, 2. revise precisely what those `M` and `N` mean, 3. resize your arrays accordingly. for instance you resize your `y` and `z` arrays with size `N`, but you write into them `M` times.

Comment: Please read the document of fgets, strsep and strtok functions. And for converting string to double, you can use strtod.

Comment: @A.S.H Do I have to edit the main topic?

Comment: @dowjie feel free to do so, but write a remark stating that you have edited your code if you do so. Also, to be clear, state whether `M` is the number of **rows** or **columns** and so for `N`.

Comment: @A.S.H I edited a mistake that I have made. I inverted M, N at some point but now it's good, in the description and the code aswell.

Comment: `x[M][N]` --> `x[N][M]` and your code should work. My feeling is, you had inverted the roles of M and N from the very beginning. In "usual" notation, M usually refers to rows and N to columns. What you have here is the reverse, but it should work.

Comment: @A.S.H it will allow me to carry on but the code doesn't work. I guess doing several fscanf doesn't follow the file in a continuous way.

Comment: I think the remaining error is due to `%g`: it works for `float` not for  `double`. Either use `%lg` or declare your numbers as `float` instead of `double`. And dont worry for `fscanf`, if your file's format corresponds well to what you suppose it to be, it works fine.

Comment: You're the man. Thank you. I already used %g for double and it worked but that was the problem right here.

Comment: @dowjie you're welcome. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete answer for your question, in addition to some conservative changes that will enhance the stability of your program. The scan code that I have used is `%lg` which is compatible with `double` data type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *f;
   f = fopen("file.txt","r");
   if(!f)
   {
      perror("file open failed");
      exit(1);
   }

   long int i, j, M, N;    
   if(fscanf(f,"%ld %ld",&M,&N) != 2) {perror("error: invalid input."); exit(1);}
   double x[M][N], y[N], z[N], t[M];

   for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      for(j = 0; j < M; j++)
      {
          if(fscanf(f,"%lg",&x[i][j]) != 1) {perror("error: invalid input."); exit(1);}
      }
      if(fscanf(f,"%lg",&y[i]) != 1) {perror("error: invalid input."); exit(1);}
      if(fscanf(f,"%lg",&z[i]) != 1) {perror("error: invalid input."); exit(1);}
   }
   for(i = 0; i < M; i++)
   {
      if(fscanf(f,"%lg",&t[i]) != 1){perror("error: invalid input."); exit(1);}
   }

   if(fclose(f))
   {
      perror ("file close failed");
      exit(1);
   }
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you really need to validate ALL user input. e.g. `if (fscanf(f,"%ld %ld",&M,&N) != 2) { fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n"); return 1; }` (you can handle the error any way you like) The same would apply to all reads. You did a good job validating your file open, just do the same for all user input.

Comment: @David C. Rankin, Good suggestion! I add it to the answer with some minor changes. This time the answer looks impenetrable. BTW, small world ;)

Comment: Solid answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the loop structure by separating the regular and irregular reads:

```
for(i=0;i<M;i++) {
  for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    fscanf(f,"%ld",&x[i][j]);
  fscanf(f,"%ld",&y[i]);
  fscanf(f,"%ld",&z[i]);
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Didn't think about that.

Comment: I think, you need to swap the place of M and N indices.